# How to create azure app service using azure powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I created an Azure Function app. Previously, I published it using GUI in visual studio. Now, I want to do that using a Powershell script.

I tried to find on MS Docs Azure RM PowerShell 6.13.0 but didn't get anything (or I miss something)

So what i should do ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available in the Microsoft official docs,

[`Creates an Azure Web App using RM module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/new-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

```
New-AzureRmWebApp
   [[-ResourceGroupName] <String>]
   [-Name] <String>
   [[-Location] <String>]
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
   [-ContainerImageName <String>]
   [-EnableContainerContinuousDeployment]
   [-AsJob]
   [-GitRepositoryPath <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

To Create **[Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/new-azurermstorageaccount?view=azurermps-6.13.0)**

```
New-AzureRmStorageAccount
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [-SkuName] <String>
   [-Location] <String>
   [-Kind <String>]
   [-AccessTier <String>]
   [-CustomDomainName <String>]
   [-UseSubDomain <Boolean>]
   [-Tag <Hashtable>]
   [-EnableHttpsTrafficOnly <Boolean>]
   [-AssignIdentity]
   [-NetworkRuleSet <PSNetworkRuleSet>]
   [-AsJob]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Set Storage Account for **[WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0)**

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
```

Final code should look like,

```
$location="West Europe"
# transform userid to lowercase since some Azure resource names don't like uppercase
$userid=$env:USERNAME.tolower()
$FuncAppName="$userid$(Get-Random)"
$rgname="$FuncAppName-rg"
$storageAccount="$($FuncAppName)stg"
$FunctionName="HttpTriggerCSharp3"

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create the resource group
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "$rgname" -Location "$location" -force

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create a storage account needed for the Function App
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "$rgname" -AccountName "$storageAccount" -Location "$location" -SkuName "Standard_LRS"
$keys = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "$rgname" -AccountName "$storageAccount"
$storageAccountConnectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=' + $storageAccount + ';AccountKey=' + $keys[0].Value

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create the Function App
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "$rgname" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/Sites" -ResourceName "$FuncAppName" -kind "functionapp" -Location "$location" -Properties @{} -force

$AppSettings = @{'AzureWebJobsDashboard' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
    'AzureWebJobsStorage' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
    'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' = '~1';
    'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
    'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE' = $storageAccount;
}
Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name "$FuncAppName" -ResourceGroupName "$rgname" -AppSettings $AppSettings
```

Comment: Hi, he asks for RM module, not az module.

Comment: In GUI, I need to create Storage Account, so where I use the account

Comment: you dont need to pass as its not mandatory, certainly you can add later if you want

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think I need to connect them now, so can you tell me how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I read the description, but still don't know what parameter (or how) for Set Storage Account for WebApp. More detail pls.

Comment: just call set account and pass the parameter

Comment: @Sajeetharan: what parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195489/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-jimmy).

Comment: did that help you?